# How to properly reset the ContinuousState in a class derived from LeafSystem?

Tags: drake

I want to write a continuous time system derived from the `LeafSystem` that can have its continuous state reset to other values if some conditions are met. However, the system does not work as what I expected. To find out the reason, I implement a simple multi-step integrator system as below:

```py
class MultiStepIntegrator(LeafSystem):
    def __init__(self):
        LeafSystem.__init__(self)
        
        self.state_index = self.DeclareContinuousState(1)
        self.DeclareStateOutputPort("x", self.state_index)
        self.flag_1 = True
        self.flag_2 = True
    
    def reset_state(self, context, value):
        state = context.get_mutable_continuous_state_vector()
        state.SetFromVector(value)
    
    def DoCalcTimeDerivatives(self, context, derivatives):
        t = context.get_time()
        if t < 2.0:
            V = [1]

        elif t < 4.0:
            if self.flag_1:
                self.reset_state(context, [0])
                print("Have done the first reset")
                self.flag_1 = False
            V = [1]
            
        else:
            if self.flag_2:
                self.reset_state(context, [0])
                print("Have done the second reset")
                self.flag_2 = False
            V = [-1]
        
        derivatives.get_mutable_vector().SetFromVector(V)
```

What I expect from this system is that it will give me a piecewise and discontinuous trajectory. Given that I set the state initially to be 0, firstly the state will go from 0 to 2 for $t \in [0,2]$, then agian from 0 to 2 for $t \in [2,4]$ and then from 0 to -2 for $t \in [4,6]$.

Then I simulate this system, and plot the logging with

```py
builder = DiagramBuilder()
plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, 1e-4)
plant.Finalize()

integrator = builder.AddSystem(MultiStepIntegrator())
state_logger = LogVectorOutput(integrator.get_output_port(), builder, 1e-2)

diagram = builder.Build()
simulator = Simulator(diagram)

log_state = state_logger.FindLog(context)
fig = plt.figure()
t = log_state.sample_times()
plt.plot(t, log_state.data()[0, :])
fig.set_size_inches(10, 6)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

It seems that the resets never happen. However I do see the two logs indicating that the resets are done:

```
Have done the first reset
Have done the second reset
```

What happened here? Are there some checkings done behind the scene that the `ContinuousState` cannot jump (as the name indicates)? How can I reset the state value given that some conditions are met?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `DoCalcTimeDerivatives`, the `context` is a const (input-only) argument.  It cannot be modified.  The only thing `DoCalcTimeDerivatives` can do is output the derivative to enable the integrator to integrate the continuous state.

Not all integrators used fixed-size time steps. Some might need to evaluate the gradients multiple times before deciding what step size(s) to use.  Therefore, it's not reasonable for a dx/dt calculation to have any side-effects.  It must be a pure function, where its only consequence is to report a dx/dt.

To change a continuous state value other than through pure integration, the System needs to use an "unrestricted update" event.  That event can mutate any and all elements of the State (including continuous state).

If the timing of the discontinuities is periodic (even if some events make no change to the state), you can use DeclarePeriodicUnrestrictedUpdateEvent to declare the update calculation.

If the discontinuities happen per a witness function, see [bouncing_ball](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/tree/master/examples/bouncing_ball) or [rimless_wheel](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/tree/master/examples/rimless_wheel) or [compass_gait](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/tree/master/examples/compass_gait) for an example.

If you need a generalized (bespoke) triggering schedule for the discontinuity events, you'll need to override DoCalcNextUpdateTime to manually inject the next event timing, something like the [LcmSubscriberSystem](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/d17871777a85ab0611dfe45aa05e6e54b21d60d8/systems/lcm/lcm_subscriber_system.cc#L94-L128).  We don't have many good examples of this to my knowledge.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have several additional questions. The first is that is the `context` in the `CalcOutput` function also a const? Can I change the state in the `CalcOutput` function? The second question is that can I have two system with one downstream system subscribing the upstream system.  The upstream system can send some event to the downstream system and depending on the event the downstream system will do something like changing of state in the current context. What is the drake's way to comminicate the event between two system? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, the `context` of `CalcOutput` is also const.  Typically the only non-const argument for any `Calc` function is the final argument (the result of the calculation).

We don't (yet?) support Event-typed ports in Drake. Ports are always either vector data or abstract values, never Events.  If you need to pass information from one System to another, it needs to happen on an Output port / Input port pair.