# Can the WitnessFunction depend on the input port?

Tags: drake

I want to write a finite state machine (FSM) like planner that has several different modes. I implement it as a system derived from the `LeafSystem` and want to use the witness function like in the [rimless_wheel](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/tree/master/examples/rimless_wheel) and the [spring-loaded inverted pendulum example](http://underactuated.csail.mit.edu/simple_legs.html) to define the transition between modes. (Follow the suggestion in the answer to my [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71884499/how-to-properly-reset-the-continuousstate-in-a-class-derived-from-leafsystem)). To do so, I define a witness function inside my class:

```py
self.touch_witness = self.MakeWitnessFunction('touch', WitnessFunctionDirection.kNegativeThenNonNegative, self.offset_vertical_force, UnrestrictedUpdateEvent(self.touch_event))
```

With the guard function `self.offset_vertical_force` defined as:

```py
def offset_vertical_force(self, context):
      F_ext = self.get_input_port(1).Eval(context)
      return F_ext[1] - 1.0
```

Here the `F_ext` is the external force sensed and `F_ext[1]` is the force on the vertical direction. In my considered scenario, at first there is no external force so `offset_vertical_force` should return -1, then after collision happens, the `offset_vertical_force` would return a NonNegative Value. Then `self.touch_event` will be trigered. (The witness function is added with the `DoGetWitnessFunctions` method.)

However, when I run the code, I find that the `self.touch_event` is never triggered, despite the fact that `self.offset_vertical_force` returns negative value first and then returns positive value. Then when I change the guard function `self.offset_vertical_force` to use some continuous state of the FSM planner itself, I do see that the event can be triggered. So my first question is that is it true that the witness function (to be more precise, the guard function) can only be defined by the system's own internal state?

However, for my purpose I need the FSM planner's mode transition be triggered by the external information. My second question is that if the witness function can only be defined by the system's own internal state, are there some workaround ways?

Apart from above, I have also tried to change the state in the `self.touch_event`

```py
def touch_event(self, context, event, state):
```

At first I tried to change the state using

```py
context.get_mutable_continuous_state_vector().SetFromVector(value)
```

However, when I run the code I see no change in the state. Then I use

```py
state.get_mutable_continuous_state().get_mutable_vector().SetFromVector(Value)
```

and when I run the code I can see the state changes. My understanding is that the `context` in the event function is const but the `state` in the event function is not. Am I right?

Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chen.

To answer your second question, yes in an event handler like touch_event() the Context is const and the handler's update is written to the mutable state object. Later the Simulator transfers the new state into the Context.

For the first question, witness functions are triggered only during continuous evolution of the full System (or Diagram) state. The integrator evaluates all witness functions at the beginning of a step, advances the state tentatively, then re-evaluates the witness functions. If a sign change is seen, then the step is revised to isolate the time of occurrence, and then the handler is called.

So there is no problem with having the witness function depend on an input port, but the value at that input port must be dependent on continuous state variables. If the input port is discrete, then the integrator sees the same value at the beginning and end of step so doesn't trigger.

I'm not sure what workaround would be appropriate for your application (hopefully someone else can provide more ideas). My first thought would be to explore whether you can make the input port dependent on continuous state.

Comment: BTW there is a detailed description of the Simulator's stepping strategy here: https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1systems_1_1_simulator.html

Comment: Another thought for a workaround: take a look at the "monitor" function that you can provide the Simulator. Your function gets called at the end of every step. If (for example) you latch a discrete input into a discrete state variable at the beginning of the step, then look at the input again in the monitor, you will be able to note a discrete sign change. Here is monitor documentation: https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1systems_1_1_simulator.html#aa92bce4d4205f51b3b17bcaae09566f7

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! In my use case, I connect the input port 1 with `MultibodyPlant`'s `generalized_contact_forces_output_port` to get the `F_ext`. I think that the input port should depend on continuous state variables (that is, the generalized state q and qdot) but there can also be some discrete dependency for that the contact is indeed a discrete event. Is this the reason that the touch_event is not triggered?

Comment: Another question is that is it ture that at one time the simulator can only have one `monitor` function? I have tried to use the `set_monitor` method, added several monitor functions and found that only the last setted `monitor` function can work. Thank you.

Comment: (1) If the MultibodyPlant is in discrete mode (time step != 0) then its output ports also only change discretely.

Comment: (2) Yes, just one monitor -- but it can be anything including a function that calls several other functions. So one monitor is sufficient -- you can have it invoke as many others as you like.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. The `monitor` function is suitable for my use case. It is quiet handy to use the `monitor` function to trigger event that does not require very strict isolation of event time.