# How can one write an FSM style discrete planner using the LeafSystem?

Tags: drake

For a project I am working on, I want to write a high-level finite state-machine planner with prescribed transitions between a set of pre-defined states. Each transition would be a different set-point control for an impedance controller (or some TrajOpt formulation). The idea is to trigger switches whenever some condition for higher-order state estimation is met. For example, robot inserting a peg into hole can be split into the approach state, align state, inserted state - writing up controllers for corresponding transitions. This is similar to a question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71956032/can-the-witnessfunction-depend-on-the-input-port), however I am not sure how it actually works on drake.

I have the low level `MultiBodyPlant` working with all the controllers working. The way I switch states right now is by using the `set_monitor` function with some time-based logic. However, I'd like to utilise `drake`'s "specify dynamics at all levels" philosophy and think about how to write a high-level planner using the `LeafSystem`. Any ideas or resources on how to go about this?

Thank you for your support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding methods to help writing finite-state machines and/or behavior trees in the systems framework has been a standing goal for me, but I'm afraid I haven't gotten to it yet.

You can find an example of writing an FSM manually in the "[clutter clearing](https://manipulation.mit.edu/clutter.html#task)" example of my manipulation notes.

The basic idea is to declare an enum

```
class PlannerState(Enum):
  WAIT_FOR_OBJECTS_TO_SETTLE = 1
  PICKING_FROM_X_BIN = 2
  PICKING_FROM_Y_BIN = 3
  GO_HOME = 4
```

then to declare an abstract state for the mode

```
  self._mode_index = self.DeclareAbstractState(
    AbstractValue.Make(PlannerState.WAIT_FOR_OBJECTS_TO_SETTLE)
  )
```

then declare a periodic unrestricted update function that works (and potentially updates) the mode

```
def Update(self, context, state):
  mode = context.get_abstract_state(int(self._mode_index)).get_value()
  ...

  if mode == PlannerState.WAIT_FOR_OBJECTS_TO_SETTLE:
    if context.get_time() - times["initial"] > 1.0:
      self.Plan(context, state)
    return
  elif mode == PlannerState.GO_HOME:
  ...
```

Comment: This is very helpful. I guess the `mode` switching happens in the `Plan` function, changing the corresponding trajectory based on the current `mode`. I'll give this a try and report here.

Comment: Do you mind if I try my hand at the `LeafSystem` FSM implementation in Drake? Would be a really nice way for me to start open source contribution to the framework.

Comment: Contributions are very welcome!  For something like this, I would recommend sketching out a rough design and getting feedback from the developers (perhaps by opening an issue with the sketch) just to make sure we have basic alignment.